# Filter rows that have value from the list in PySpark

Tags: list, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, filter

I have a list of values:

```py
my_list = ["temp1","temp2", "temp10", "temp15"]
```

I am trying to delete rows from the column "value" that has the values from this list.

**Code I tried:**

```py
res = res.filter((res.value == 'temp1') | (res.value == 'temp2') |
                 (res.value == 'temp10') | (res.value == 'temp15'))
```

But is there any other way that I can directly loop in the list and filter? (because my list has 30 elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin`:

```py
res = res.filter(res.value.isin(my_list))
```

Example:

```py
res = spark.createDataFrame([('temp1',), ('x',)], ['value'])
res.show()
# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# |temp1|
# |    x|
# +-----+

my_list = ["temp1", "temp2", "temp10", "temp15"]
res = res.filter(res.value.isin(my_list))

res.show()
# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# |temp1|
# +-----+
```